Prove that the order type of $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is the antilexicographic order in $\alpha\times\beta$.
This question is related to this one, but not a duplicate, since I am struggling with injectivity and monotonicity, rather than proving that $\{\alpha\cdot\eta + \xi:\eta<\beta\textrm{ and }\xi<\alpha\} = \alpha\cdot\beta.$
I am trying to prove the following theorem from the book Introduction to Set Theory by Karel Hrbaceck and Thomas Jech.

Theorem
Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinal numbers. Both the lexicographic and the antilexicographic orderings of the product $\alpha\times\beta$ are well orderings. the order type of the antilexicographic ordering of $\alpha\times\beta$ are well-orderings. The ordering of $\alpha\times\beta$ is $\alpha\cdot\beta$, while the lexicographic ordering of $\alpha\times\beta$ has order type $\beta\cdot\alpha$.
Proof. Let $\prec$ denote the antilexicographic ordering of $\alpha\times\beta$. We define an isomorphism between $(\alpha\times\beta,\prec)$ and $\alpha\cdot\beta$ as follows: for $\xi<\alpha$ and $\eta<\beta$ let $f(\xi,\eta)=\alpha\cdot\eta+\xi$. The range of $f$ is the set $\{\alpha\cdot\eta+\xi:\eta<\beta\,and\,\xi<\alpha\}=\alpha\cdot\beta$ and $f$ is an isomorphism (we leave the details -proved by induction- to the reader; see also Exercieses 5.1,5.2,5.7 and 5.8)

I was able to prove by induction that $f$ is surjective but I was not to prove it is injective and monotone: to follow my proof attempt.
Let be $\theta,\delta\in\alpha$ and $\eta,\gamma\in\beta$ such that the inequality
$$
(\theta,\eta)\prec(\delta,\gamma)
$$
holds. So we can evaluate the following two cases:

$\theta<\delta\wedge\eta=\gamma$;
$\eta<\gamma$.

So let's we assube firt $\theta<\delta$ and $\eta=\gamma$: if $\eta=\gamma$ then $\alpha\eta=\alpha\gamma$ so that my strictly left-monotonicity of sum we have
$$
f(\theta,\eta)=\alpha\eta+\theta<\alpha\gamma+\delta=f(\delta,\gamma)
$$
Now let's we assume $\eta<\gamma$ and thus we can evaluate the following two (sub)cases:

$\theta<\delta$;
$\delta\le\theta$.

So if $\eta<\gamma$ then $\alpha\eta\le\alpha\gamma$ so that by left-monotonicity $\alpha\eta+\theta\le\alpha\gamma+\theta$ and thus by strictly left-monotonicity $\alpha\eta+\theta\le\alpha\gamma+\theta<\alpha\gamma+\delta$: we conclude the inequality
$$
f(\theta,\eta)=\alpha\eta+\theta<\alpha\gamma+\delta=f(\delta,\gamma)
$$
holds.
Now I was not able to prove the last case where $\eta<\gamma$ and $\delta\le\theta$ so that I thought to put here a specific question: how can I prove the inequality
$$
f(\theta,\eta)<f(\delta,\gamma)
$$
even holds? could someone help me, please?
To follow the original text: I put here there since I could be possible I omitted something I did not see.


Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity Sorry, I do not really understand since I use many times pictures. However I can copy the what it is written into the immage: give me some minutes.

Also, please don't yell at the members of the community.

Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity I copied the image: I did not want yell to you, absolutely; I just observed I did this many times and so I was surprising by this since I am not new, that's all; forgive if I offended

What is it you don't understand? My comment has several reasons why pictures are a bad idea - all points to the same: copy what is written in the image. It doesn't really matter that you've used pictures before, that doesn't make it good idea to keep it up,

@Henriksupportsthecommunity Well I did not understand since the picture I put it is readable I think, that's all.

It might have been readable, but that only "solves" one of the problems with using pictures.

One key remark about your proof attempt is that the ordinal addition and multiplication operations are not generally strictly monotone in the left argument, but rather, in the right.
As for where you're stuck, you don't need subcases. If $\eta<\gamma,$ then $\eta+1\leq\gamma,$ and since $\theta<\alpha,$ then $$\alpha\cdot\eta+\theta<\alpha\cdot\eta+\alpha=\alpha\cdot(\eta+1).$$
Can you justify this and take it from there?

So if $\eta<\gamma$ then $\alpha\cdot\eta+\theta<\alpha\cdot\eta+\alpha=\alpha\cdot(\eta+1)\le\alpha\cdot\gamma\le\alpha\cdot\gamma+\delta$, right?

Yep! All you need to do is justify each step appropriately.

Well, actually by strictely left-monotonicitity we have the inequality $\alpha\cdot\eta+\theta<\alpha\cdot(\eta+1)$ whereas by monotonicity of multiplication we have $\alpha\cdot(\eta+1)\le\alpha\cdot\gamma$ and finally by left-monotonicity of summ we have $\alpha\cdot\gamma=\alpha\cdot\gamma+0\le\alpha\cdot\gamma+\delta$, right?

Not quite. $\alpha\cdot\eta+\theta<\alpha\cdot\eta+\alpha$ by strict monotonicity of addition in the right argument, not the left. Then we use left-distributivity of multiplication over addition. The last step is once again due to strict monotonicity of addition in the right argument, not the left.

Okay, all clear: I  used term "left" since the equal term appear on the left, that's all; however if you say it is usual to use the term "right" I will do it starting by now. Thanks really much for the help: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks yet! :-)
